# Quick question concerning: If G, a finite group and for p prime, $p||G|$, prove that the number of elements of order $p$ in $G$ is a multiple of $p-1$

Tags: group-theory

If a prime $p$ divides the order of a finite group $G$, prove that the number of elements of order $p$ in $G$ is a multiple of $p-1$

If a subgroup $H$ of $G$ has order $p$, then the total number of nonidentity elements of order $p$ in $H$ is $p-1$.  Can I assume that $G$ has $k$ number of subgroups of order $p$ where $k\geq 1$.  So if $b\in G$ has order $p$ and we can let $<b>=H_k$.  If $b\in H_i\cap H_j,$ for $i\neq j$, then $<b>=H_i=H_j.$, etc.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I am just wondering if I am allowing to assume that the group $G$ has more than one subgroup of order $p$ for $p$-prime.  Is a matter of proof writing what I am allow or not allow to assume.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net thank you for the comment and reference link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $H_1$ and $H_2$ are **distinct** subgroups of order $p$, then $H_1\cap H_2=\{e\}$.

And yes, there is a positive number $k$ of subgroups of order $p$.

An element of order $p$ cannot belong to two different subgroups of order $p$,

so the number of elements of order $p$ is obviously $k(p-1)$.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me.  I wasn't sure what I am allow to assume since the group $G$ can have only one group of order $p$ for $p$ prime.

Comment: thank you for clarifying for me